# Average Count of Columns with 2 groupby Condition in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data table that consists of multiple variables based on the number of visits to each venue daily. I wanted to find the average visit count of each venue for Sat and Mon.

I tried using the code but the output looks weird where the count for both days is the same. I do think that the output of the average count should be different based on the data I have.

```
new_data_selected <- new_data %>%
  select(c("venueType", "buildingId", "day", "n")) %>%
  filter (day == "Mon"| day == "Sat") %>%
  group_by(buildingId,day) %>%
  summarise(Mean_visit = mean(n))
```

I created a random 25 rows of sample data to generate the dput.

```
dput(sample_data)

structure(list(venueType = c("Restaurant", "Pub", "Pub", "Restaurant", 
"Pub", "Restaurant", "Pub", "Restaurant", "Pub", "Pub", "Pub", 
"Pub", "Restaurant", "Pub", "Restaurant", "Restaurant", "Pub", 
"Restaurant", "Pub", "Restaurant", "Pub", "Pub", "Pub", "Restaurant", 
"Restaurant"), buildingId = c("86", "238", "585", "164", "502", 
"917", "556", "160", "502", "429", "29", "238", "917", "627", 
"27", "181", "238", "101", "164", "101", "502", "953", "29", 
"991", "160"), location = structure(list(structure(c(-820.92902794796, 
4497.24330853014), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-1702.53781555412, 
3865.47709084848), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-225.920986645022, 
3878.05369762611), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-1623.07405914413, 
3872.0300113645), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-1524.95732116621, 
3815.27149011437), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-1771.45221663564, 
4343.58017658314), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(964.43802317132, 
3991.60347378421), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-3136.12789580931, 
6671.91746186715), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-1524.95732116621, 
3815.27149011437), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-260.457470531391, 
5026.15080417936), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(1809.88017335787, 
4339.17242603545), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-1702.53781555412, 
3865.47709084848), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-1771.45221663564, 
4343.58017658314), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-3796.11985138919, 
6367.92207258208), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-3529.55838697545, 
4809.64112766693), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(1407.71076951492, 
4010.45748152692), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-1702.53781555412, 
3865.47709084848), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-4131.41409222454, 
7236.52563322564), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-1608.76641144993, 
3886.49247849546), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-4131.41409222454, 
7236.52563322564), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-1524.95732116621, 
3815.27149011437), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-3209.73813918762, 
6487.6576880651), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(1809.88017335787, 
4339.17242603545), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-1176.80133020324, 
5846.64712423648), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-3136.12789580931, 
6671.91746186715), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_POINT", 
"sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = -4131.41409222454, 
ymin = 3815.27149011437, xmax = 1809.88017335787, ymax = 7236.52563322564
), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(input = NA_character_, 
    wkt = NA_character_), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L), daynum = c(17L, 
11L, 9L, 3L, 19L, 8L, 27L, 22L, 31L, 15L, 2L, 27L, 18L, 22L, 
16L, 1L, 10L, 22L, 5L, 31L, 17L, 13L, 4L, 6L, 10L), day = structure(c(5L, 
4L, 7L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 6L), levels = c("Sun", "Mon", "Tue", 
"Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), 
    n = c(982L, 741L, 1701L, 2020L, 835L, 423L, 622L, 1595L, 
    412L, 1703L, 742L, 532L, 413L, 998L, 216L, 1432L, 686L, 540L, 
    2104L, 258L, 729L, 1064L, 761L, 880L, 1609L)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -25L), groups = structure(list(
    buildingId = c("101", "101", "160", "160", "164", "164", 
    "181", "238", "238", "238", "27", "29", "29", "429", "502", 
    "502", "502", "556", "585", "627", "86", "917", "917", "953", 
    "991"), daynum = c(22L, 31L, 10L, 22L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 10L, 11L, 
    27L, 16L, 2L, 4L, 15L, 17L, 19L, 31L, 27L, 9L, 22L, 17L, 
    8L, 18L, 13L, 6L), .rows = structure(list(18L, 20L, 25L, 
        8L, 4L, 19L, 16L, 17L, 2L, 12L, 15L, 11L, 23L, 10L, 21L, 
        5L, 9L, 7L, 3L, 14L, 1L, 6L, 13L, 22L, 24L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -25L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for providing sample data but since you did `dput(head(new_data, 10))`, it only contains the first 10 values and all `day` values are "Tue", so the `filter()` returns nothing for us trying to help. Could you randomly sample the rows in your data then do `dput`? I would also suggest at least 20-25 observations when troubleshooting something like a summary statistic by group (to ensure each group has some data). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The below code seems to work for me, though if it doesn't work for you, there may be additional packages loaded that interfere with some `dplyr` functions. First try this code:

```
# only one "Mon" or "Sat" per group in the provided data, so changing to add more
set.seed(123)
new_data$day <- sample(c("Mon","Tue","Sat"), nrow(new_data), replace = TRUE)

new_data %>%
  filter(day %in% c("Sat", "Mon")) %>%
  group_by(buildingId, day) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(Mean_visit = mean(n)))

#   buildingId day   Mean_visit
# <chr>      <chr>      <dbl>
# 1 101        Mon         258 
# 2 101        Sat         540 
# 3 160        Sat        1609 
# 4 164        Mon        2104 
# 5 181        Mon        1432 
# 6 238        Sat         714
```

If that doesn't work, try unloading all packages and loading back in `dplyr`:

```
invisible(lapply(
  paste0('package:', names(sessionInfo()$otherPkgs)),
  detach,
  character.only = TRUE,
  unload = TRUE
))
library(dplyr)
```

If that doesn't work, perhaps edit the question to include some more of your data or any errors and we'll figure this thing out.

Comment: Interesting, both my value for Sat and Mon for all the buildingId is the same. Which means for buildingId 101, both sat and mon is the same value. Same goes to all the buildingId

Comment: Even on the sample data? Hmm. Did you try running the code to uninstall packages? Also, try running `dplyr::summarise(Mean_visit = mean(n)))` (see edited code in answer)